# Creation of Dependent Resource in RESTful API

Tags: laravel, api, rest

I am bit confused about the implementation of RESTful best practices.

I have a `customer` resource and `license` resource. Customer is required for license creation. My doubt is can I combine the customer object in the `license` creation request so that service will check the existence and create customer conditionally and then create the license for the customer.

Scenario 1 - Create Customer and then Create License separately with customer identifier.

`POST /customers`

```
{
   'email': 'user-1@example.com',
   'mobile': '9876543210'
}
```

`POST /licenses`

```
{
   'customer': {
        'email': 'user-1@example.com',
    },
    'expire_at': '2021-12-31'
}
```

Scenario 2 - Create License with customer details. (Customer will be created automatically if not exists)

`POST /licenses`

```
{
   'customer': {
        'email': 'user-2@example.com',
        'mobile': '9876543210'
    },
    'expire_at': '2021-12-31'
}
```

Is scenario 2 violating the RESTful concept?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am bit confused about the implementation of RESTful best practices.

Not your fault; there is a lot of confusing information about REST on the internet.

> Is scenario 2 violating the RESTful concept?

Heuristic: how would you do this on a website?

Which is to say, is it sensible to have a web page with one form, with input constrols for customer email, customer mobile, and expire_at, that when submitted copies the data into a single HTTP request which is dispatched to the server?

```
POST /licenses HTTP/x.y
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

email=user-2@example.com&phone=9876543210&expire_at=2021-12-31
```

Web sites do that all the time; it's *fine*.  So having your API do the analogous thing is also going to be fine.

---

`/licenses` may or may not be the best target-uri.  It's fine, but there are some [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) implications that could mean using a different resource would be better (depending on the specifics of your URI design, and which documents you want clients to refresh immediately).

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of these, there is no REST constraint that forbids the creation of multiple resources with a single HTTP request. It is a good idea to document this in your API description.

On the other hand I would rather split your `createLicenseOrLicenseAndCustomer -> POST /licenses` operation into `createLicenseAndCustomer -> POST /licenses/and/customers`, `createLicense -> POST /licenses` and `createCustomer -> POST /customers`. At least it feels better this way because of the KISS principle. But this really depends on the taste of the API designer. From error handling perspective it is interesting too, because you can have an error for license creation but a success for customer creation. If you use database trasactions and rollback, then this partial success/failure does not happen though.